# Dynamically adding textbox in Html

Tags: javascript, html

```
 function change() {
        var select = document.getElementById("slct");
        var divv = document.getElementById("container");
        var value = select.value;
        for (i = 0; i <value; i++) { 
            toAppend += "<input type='textbox' >";

        }
        divv.innerHTML=toAppend;`enter code here`
        return;
     }
```

I Have this code and I am calling it by dropdown menu

```
<select id="slct" onchange="change();">
     <option value="0"> select value </option>
   <option value="1"> 1 </option>
     <option value="2"> 2 </option>
   <option value="3"> 3 </option>
```

but its not showing anything

Comment: use option instead of select.value...

Comment: Just adding declaring toAppend as an empty string will do the work, [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mkdskd/mmm15971/)

Comment: make a habbit of looking at the console, it helps a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `var toAppend=''` before the `for` loop